# POSTing text contents as if it were coming from a "file" input

Tags: jquery, http, post, file-upload

I need to take the contents from a textarea (really, an Ace Editor) and POST it to a server if the the text contents was really sent via a `<input type="file" ..`

I have to do it this way as the backend system i'm POSTing to is expecting this format; I have no control over this system. I simply want to post a blob of text as if it were coming from a text file.

I will be sending the data using jQuery.post(..) so I have all the flexibility that provides, along w any custom wrapping functionality.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple enough:

As soon as a file get's posted, you will get a POST_DATA field as actual post data.
This is how POST_DATA looks:

```
-----------------------------278642518110014\r\n
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="usrname"; filename="SuperEngine.ncp"\r\n
Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n
CONTENT
```

Where:

**278642518110014** = Timestamp in milliseconds

**name="usrname"** = name of html form field (the textbox in your case)

**filename="SuperEngine.ncp"** = name of the file (can be made up!)

**CONTENT** = raw data of file (content of textbox in your case)

Construct this post data with jQuery and your server will think that you posted this data with an input type=file field.